# How to validate multiple inputs every focusout event using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Good day everyone, I'm having a problem on validating my inputs using `focusout` event. What i wan't is, every time the input was `focusout` it will validate that input only without affecting the other inputs. The problem is i have a lot of inputs and i wan't it with the same id. That's the problem because when one of my inputs triggered it validate all. I had a lot of research to this and some where relevant to my question but i still i don't get it and i'm new to programming. I need help please!

heres the link: https://jsfiddle.net/m7wa35tc/

```js
var Main = {

 init: function(){
   this.handleBinds();

 },

 handleBinds: function(){

  $('.required').on("keyup", function(){
   if($.trim($(this).val()).length < 1){
    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
   }else{
    $(this).css("border-color", "");
   }
   
  });

 }

};
 $(document).ready(function(){

 Main.init();

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Name
     <input type="text" id="required">
</label>
<br>
<label>Corporate or Legal Name
     <input type="text" id="required">
</label>
<br>
<label>Location Address
     <input type="text" id="required">
</label>
<br>
<label>City, State
     <input type="text" id="required">
</label>
<br>
<label>Zip/Postal Code
     <input type="text" id="required">
</label>
<br>
<label>Country
     <input type="text" id="required">
</label>
<br>
<label>Email Addresse
     <input type="text" id="required">
</label>
```

Comment: Please post your current solution in a JSFiddle or code snippet, so that we can provide some help.

Comment: Wait? You have multiple inputs, with the same ID? ID is **unique** - there can be only **one** of each ID on every page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response i updated now my post. I put some only of my inputs.

Comment: Aw so i need to use class not id?

Comment: Thank you for the response Michael Camden and junkfoodjunkie. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set unique id to each element you want to make reference, in this case use class="required" instead

Comment: Thank you it's working. I change the id to class. I have follow-up question, how can i validate the email also?

Comment: Do you want to validate the email format? can try with regular expresion:

Comment: $('.email').on("keyup", function(){
   var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
   if(!reg.test($(this).val())){
    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
   }else{
    $(this).css("border-color", "");
   }
  }); // I think this will do the work, add it to your handleBinds function and add the email function to your email input

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate it.